# remove objects and save change using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

i want remove player from list player but i can not i use relation OneTomany 
but update does not remove the player

public void delete_player(Player playerId,Member member){

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

```
    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();

    tx.begin();  
    try {
        member.getPlayers().remove(playerId);

        session.saveOrUpdate(member);

          tx.commit();

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        tx.rollback();

    }
    }
```

Comment: Ensure that you've added your collection with cascade.ALL annotation

Comment: if you have a bi-directional association, you should also do playerId.setMember(null);

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
 @JoinTable(name = "preference_player", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "identifier"),@JoinColumn(name = "connectionType") }, 
 inverseJoinColumns = {
   @JoinColumn(name = "playerId") })
 @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
 protected List<Player> players;

Comment: no i have uniderectionel association but i can not remove player from players